# Python subprocess with pipes is blocking when reading stdout

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pipe

I am attempting to open the cmd.exe proccess, write to stdin, and then read the output form stdout.

I have created 2 pipes for input and output:

```
read_in, write_in = os.pipe()
read_out, write_out = os.pipe()
```

I then open the cmd.exe process:

```
proc = SB.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=False, stdin=read_in, stdout=write_out, stderr=write_out)
```

Then i read the headers from cmd.exe:

```
>>> os.read(read_out, 200)
b'Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778]\r\n(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\\blabla>'
```

Then i write a commnd to the input:

```
os.write(write_in, b"ipconfig")
```

But when i read from stdout, nothing happens and it just blocks:

```
os.read(read_out, 200)
```

Here is the total code:

```
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess as SB
>>> read_in, write_in = os.pipe()
>>> read_out, write_out = os.pipe()
>>> proc = SB.Popen("cmd.exe", shell=False, stdin=read_in, stdout=write_out, stderr=write_out)
>>> os.read(read_out, 200)
b'Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778]\r\n(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:>'
>>> os.write(write_in, b"ipconfig")
8
>>> os.read(read_out, 200)
```

I am aware of the `subprocess.PIPE` and `process.communicate()` method, but i am after using a different set of file descriptors/pipes

Comment: You aren't writing a newline to `cmd.exe`'s input for it to actually execute the given command.

Comment: ...that said, I would *strongly* suggest using `pexpect` if you want to drive a shell. It's written for the purpose; you're otherwise going to need to reinvet much of what it does.

Comment: Thank you, i should know about the `\n`, guess it just didnt click